# How do I count one value and then count distinct another one in Qlik

Tags: distinct, qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to count how many times all my machines stopped and then I want to count distinct and see how many machines have stopped. 
So **how many times** they stopped - and **how many of the machines** stopped

```
    count(DISTINCT MachineNumber if ({$<Program = {"DETECT    
    STOP"}>})MachineNumber)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 expressions

Number of Machines:
  `count({$<Program = {"DETECT STOP"}>} DISTINCT MachineNumber)`

Number of Stop Events:
  `count({$<Program = {"DETECT STOP"}>} MachineNumber)`